# page shows 404 on form submit

Tags: page-template, forms

I have creating a template page in which i have a form, upon testing it gave a 404 error. should i putting something else in action?

```
`<form action="results.php" method="post">
    <!--my code-->
</form>`
```

Comment: It would help to know what context this form is in.

Comment: @s_ha_dum couple of Questions, in form on MCQ's and when clicked submit, i will pull results from categories based on selected radio buttons

Comment: What is "MCQ"? Does the form appear on only one page or on multiple pages?

Comment: @s_ha_dum MCQ are multiple choice questions, like a question says, what is the day of week today? and you have couple of radio button which says the days and you choose one. that is MCQ :), yes the pages i have are two, one is form which has mcq and other will have the results. (pulled from category based on choices made)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i putting something else in action?

Yes. The complete path to the file. If your site is `http://mysite.com` and you are on the home page then you are requesting a file at `http://mysite.com/result.php`. If you are on a date archive you'd be requesting a file at `http://mysite.com/2013/03/03/result.php`. The file you want is actually at `http://mysite.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/result.php`. See the problem?

[Relative URLs do not work well in a WordPress context.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:21376%20relative%20urls)

But I would say that even if you were to construct a complete URL to the template file that you are still doing it wrong. If you load a file like that then none of the WordPress core loads and you tend to get undefined function errors.

The right way to do this, in my opinion, is ...

1. to send the request to the same template file as contains the form.

   ```
   <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post">
   ```

   That particular code only works in some circumstances so you may
   need to construct the URL differently, using `site_url()`, for example. You can usually just omit the action attribute (as prompted by Milo).
2. You could also hook a function to `template_redirect` or `wp_head`
   and process the form on that hook.
3. Or, use the AJAX API to process the form submission. Of course, that
   means some Javascript as well.

If you form appears on more than one page you will need one of option 2 or 3. Otherwise, use the first option.

If you need the form to appear on one page and the results on another, then you will need a custom page template for each component, and you will need to [create a page for the form and another for the results via the "Pages" section of the WordPress backend](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages).

Comment: You can omit the action attribute altogether and the form will always submit to the current URI.

Comment: @s_ha_dum i don't know option 2 or 3 as not familiar with it. however if i use 
`<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post"> ` how will it know which one to get as i haven't told it which page has the result.

Comment: @Milo : yeah, you can, but I don't like to... personality quirk maybe.

Comment: @AmmarKhan : If you go with option 1 your form processing code must be in the same file as the form.

Comment: @s_ha_dum the page not found. here is my [code](http://pastebin.aquilenet.fr/?b1a1e2eafbdaed12#6J7hXaRRtsjFk5y6TCveGWNm/Pe6cOiqyDS3koX0xOQ=)

Comment: The code works fine. You are doing something strange and I can't work out what.

Comment: @s_ha_dum the code on page work fine, but when i click submit, it shows me a 404. is it same with you? i do have a child theme in which i am using it. if it helps.

Comment: Yes, if you follow the instructions it works. Create a page called 'results' and add the shortcode to it. It works. Or create a page called 'quiz' and add the shortcode, and then create a page called 'results' to process the shortcode. It works in that case as well. You must have pretty permalinks enabled, given that you have partially hardcoded the URLs.

Comment: @s_ha_dum i tired but still, "page not found" my result page has the following code 
        `$que1 = $_POST['q1'];
          echo $que1;`
should be the result page under theme dir or plugins or parent theme?

Comment: It needs to be a [WordPRess Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages).

Comment: @s_ha_dum it worked! Thank you. silly me, i didn't thought u needed to make a page tempalte

Comment: If this solved the question please [mark it as "Accepted"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). Look for the check mark on the left.